# Pivot Table Field has no items

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pivot-table

I am working on a series of pivot tables on Excel, for which I would like a particular filter to be automated in the following way: the user inputs a particular value in one cell, and all the filters across the workbook refresh accordingly. I have been reading posts in Stack Exchange which explain how to do it. However, I have come across an issue which I have been unable to solve.

My data comes from an external Microsoft Access database. I have created a connexion between the database and the Excel file; the data is imported to the Excel file where it is displayed as a table `tblExcel`. My pivot tables are then linked to this `tblExcel`.

To refresh filters, I want to use the following line:

```
item.Visible = (item.Caption = cd)
```

where `item` is a `PivotItems` object and `cd` is the value inputted by the user. This line wasn't working, so I wrote the following subroutine to check something:

```
Sub Test()

check = 0

For Each field In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("[tblExcel].[Field1].[Field1]").PivotItems
    check = check + 1
Next

MsgBox check

End Sub
```

It turns out that the `MsgBox` returns invariably a 0, for all my fields, like they were empty.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Is it due to my data model structure? How could I circumvent it?

Comment: which Pivot field name are you trying to filter ?

Comment: The one called `"[tblExcel].[Field1].[Field1]"`.

Comment: `[tblExcel]` is your source data, right ? you are trying to filter `Field1` in that source ?

Comment: Yep, I import data from Access as a Table. The Table is then linked to the Access database. The Table itself is in Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code, for debug purposes you have an `InputBox`, where you write down the ***Field1*** value you want the PIVOT Table to filter to.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Filter_PivotTable_Items()

Dim PvtTbl                              As PivotTable
Dim pvtFld                              As PivotField
Dim cd                                  As String

' setting the Pivot Table to a PivotTable Object
Set PvtTbl = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' set Pivot table to show only the selected Project's Data
Set pvtFld = PvtTbl.PivotFields("Field1")

' select manually the value for Field 1 >> for debug purpose
cd = InputBox("Select Item")
Call SelectPivotItem(pvtFld, cd)

End Sub


Public Sub SelectPivotItem(Field As PivotField, cd As String)

Dim Item                            As PivotItem

On Error GoTo cd_Error
For Each Item In Field.PivotItems
    Item.Visible = (Item.Caption = cd)
Next

cd_Error:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Item " & cd & " not found !"
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```